# How do I save data of a browser extension?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

This is my first time making a browser extension, for firefox. I have no idea or clue on how to make it so that when the user clicks on the extension on the extension bar, types/paste anything on the text in the popup, then click out of it, then click on the extension again and it will retain whatever was last typed on the textarea. This will retain the values even across pages and sites.

Here are the extension I'm working on:

Manifest:

```
{

    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Automate Extract links",
    "version": "1.0",

    "description": "Extracts links from a page",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<any_site>"],
            "js": ["borderify.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "storage"
    ]
}
```

The popup (in the subfolder `popup`), contains just the textarea:

```
<textarea id="InputListOfURLs" cols="75" rows="30" style="white-space: pre; overflow-wrap: normal; overflow-x: scroll;"></textarea>
```

I really don't know how to use the API. I'm really new to this.

Answer (score 0):

By "the extension on the extension bar", I assume you mean that you want your extension to display an icon for itself in the toolbar, and then display a pop up when that's clicked. [This guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Add_a_button_to_the_toolbar) shows how you can do that. It describes using a background script, which isn't limited to one webpage, which you'd need so the data is retained across different websites. Your data is simple, so you can just store it within that script in an in-memory data structure such as an array.

Comment: Uhh, I'm not into that, I'm saying I click on the extension, it presents a textarea, oninput, when I type, saves whatever I type into a storage. If I close the popup via clickout out of it, the data remains saved. If I click on the extension again to reopen the popup, it retains what I last type. I'm asking how do I save and load the save data?

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean by "I click on the extension"? Running a browser with an extension installed doesn't, in of itself, cause anything to render which you can then click on.

It's hard to answer technical questions that aren't precise about their goals. Another thing you could clarify is what you mean by "save and load the save data". It was helpful that you noted you want it to be preserved across websites. What about, for example, if you restart the browser? I recommend you express these details by describing what a user of your software could do and what result they would then get.

Comment: I mean if you click the extension on the toolbar of a browser that is running, it brings up a popup of just a textbox - a textarea. Every edit I type will be saved, so things like that popup closing, closing or switching tabs, and closing and reopening the browser, it will be saved. You open the popup by clicking on the extension again, and it will retain the text you last typed on. This tool: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-multiple-urls/oifijhaokejakekmnjmphonojcfkpbbh is an example that it saves what I typed.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the guide I linked to earlier shows what you need to know. Just like the guide, you want to add a button to the toolbar and display a pop up when it's clicked. To be clear, you need to replace their sample HTML with your own (the text area). The guide shows how you can set an event listener to run a JavaScript function when the user interacts with the popup. Instead of listening for an `onclick` event, you might want to listen for an `onchange` event, so you can save the data in the text area every time the user changes it.

Comment: The guide uses a [background script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Background_scripts), which means you don't have to worry about switching tabs affecting anything. But to store data in between sessions you'll need to use [this API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage), which I found by googling "firefox extension save data between sessions".